# Calculate Pandas dataframe column - boolean logic and offset data

Tags: python, pandas, boolean-logic

Based on information in a Pandas Dataframe I would like to calculate a new column. Below is an example of what I would like to do. Starting point:

{'A': [1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0]}

Based on this data I would like to calculate a new column B by using the following logic: IF (A(row-2) = 1 AND A(row -1) = 1) then B(row) = 1 ELSE B(row) = 0. I would like to get this result:

{'A': [1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0], 'B': [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]}

Is this possible without looping through the dataframe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `d` is your DataFrame:

```
>>> d['B'] = ((d.A.shift(2)==1) & (d.A.shift(1)==1)).astype(int)
>>> d
   A  B
0  1  0
1  1  0
2  0  1
3  0  0
4  1  0
5  1  0
6  0  1
7  0  0
8  0  0
```

`shift` is the way to shift a column forward or backward, allowing you compare values in different rows.  The parenthesized expression with `&` return the results you want but as booleans (True and False) rather than 1 and 0, so I used `.astype(int)` to turn them into 1 and 0.  Depending on what you need to do this may not be necessary since booleans also are integers so will work in integer calculations.

Comment: Thanks! Additional question: If I do not know the name of the column but knows that I'm going to make the calculation based on the first column, in this case A. How do I reference this column in the formula?